# Is Worklight-CLI installer broken?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-cli

I'm trying out the Worklight CLI tools in order to automate the setup of new Worklight projects. The problem is that downloading the latest (at the time of writing) version **201409222259** from Fix Central it seems that the bundled `generator-worklight` and `generator-worklight-server` node modules are empty (they contain only dependencies). The result is that once having completed the installation, executing the `wl` tool gives me this error:

```
D:\>wl help

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\IBM\Worklight-CLI\worklight-cli\bin\worklight-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

(Note, I'm installing on Windows 8.1, following the instructions on setting compatibility mode)

Checking the previous versions up to now, it seems that this problem appeared as of version **201409181910**, whereas previous versions (e.g. **201409171241**) contain all expected resources. Finally, even checking the file sizes on Fix Central the problem seems obvious since the CLI bundle size dropped from about 367MB to 236MB for version **201409181910** (the first problematic one).

My question is: Is the CLI's installer indeed broken in the last versions or is there a different installation approach that needs to be followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new Interim Fix, 201410022218, which addresses the CLI issue is now available on Fix Central.  You do not need to upgrade your server components to utilize the CLI fix, although not doing so may prevent you from taking advantage of some of the other fixes that were added since your previous update.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Just checked version 201410022218 and indeed it seems complete.

Answer (score 1):

The versions you've mentioned are indeed broken and are in the process of being back-leveled; check again soon to download an older, working, version.

The CLI is currently in the process of getting fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Idan. Our project is currently using version 201409222259. Using an older version of the CLI (which we are now doing) is ok but we need to open the CLI-generated project in WL studio to have it migrated to our current version (i.e. no continuous integration is possible). On the other hand, if a new CLI version is released with a new general fix pack, we will need to also upgrade all our projects/servers to the new version (which we normally want to do only after we have thoroughly tested a new version). My question is: is a fixed CLI for version 201409222259 possible?